# Manipulation uwp c# updating position in a grid

Tags: c#, events, uwp

I am trying to make a system where i have a grid with UI Elements in that's can moved around into positions to create a custom form.

At the Moment i am using Manipulation, this is my code

```
    void OBJManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        forceManipulationsToEnd = false;

        if (sender is TextBlock)
        {
            TextBlock temp = sender as TextBlock;
            _transformOrginalColor = temp.Foreground;
            temp.RenderTransform = _transformGroup;
            temp.Opacity = 0.5;
            temp.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 192, 57, 43));
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }

    void OBJManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBlock)
        {
            TextBlock temp = sender as TextBlock;

            if (forceManipulationsToEnd)
            {
                e.Complete();
                return;
            }

            _previousTransform.Matrix = _transformGroup.Value;
            Windows.Foundation.Point center = _previousTransform.TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point(e.Position.X, e.Position.Y));

            _compositeTransform.CenterX = center.X;
            _compositeTransform.CenterY = center.Y;

            _compositeTransform.Rotation = (e.Delta.Rotation * 180) / Math.PI;
            _compositeTransform.ScaleX = _compositeTransform.ScaleY = e.Delta.Scale;
            _compositeTransform.TranslateX = e.Delta.Translation.X;
            _compositeTransform.TranslateY = e.Delta.Translation.Y;



            e.Handled = true;

        }

    }

    void OBJManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        if (sender is TextBlock)
        {
            TextBlock temp = sender as TextBlock;
            temp.Opacity = 1;
            temp.Foreground = _transformOrginalColor;
            //forceManipulationsToEnd = true;
            //temp.RenderTransform = null;
            //InitManipulationTransforms();
        }
    }


    private void UpdateQuote()
    {
        foreach(UIElement element in Base_Template.Children)
        {
            element.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;
            element.ManipulationStarting += new ManipulationStartingEventHandler(OBJManipulationStarted);
            element.ManipulationDelta += new ManipulationDeltaEventHandler(OBJManipulationDelta);
            element.ManipulationCompleted += new ManipulationCompletedEventHandler(OBJManipulationCompleted);
            UISEL_ELEMENTS.Add(element);
            if (element is TextBlock)
            {
                TextBlock temp = element as TextBlock;
                GridEditTool elementGET = new GridEditTool("TEXT", temp.Name);
                Hiarcey.Items.Add(elementGET);
            }

            if (element is Grid)
            {
                Grid temp = element as Grid;
                if ((string)temp.Tag != "INC")
                {
                    GridEditTool elementGET = new GridEditTool("SOLID BLOCK", temp.Name);
                    Hiarcey.Items.Add(elementGET);
                }
                else
                {
                    GridEditTool elementGET = new GridEditTool("INFO BLOCK", temp.Name);
                    Hiarcey.Items.Add(elementGET);
                }
            }


        }
```

Using this it works i can click on a UI Element it will follow the mouse then will stop when you realise mouse, but then when i click on another UI Element it move both of them. I am using Padding Left and Top for position and when i look at this value after i have moved the Object it is still the same, Is their a way i can do this with manipulation or could someone please suggest a alternative?

Comment: Do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but then when i click on another UI Element it move both of them. I am using Padding Left and Top for position and when i look at this value after i have moved the Object it is still the same.

The problem is you have set the same `_transformGroup` to different `UIElement` in the `ManipulationStarted` event handler. After manipulated the fist element the `_transformGroup` had saved the first element position. And the second element will move to the same position when manipulation start.

For your requirement you could make a class to store the separate `TransformGroup` like the follow:

```
public class ElementTransform
{
    public MatrixTransform _previousTransform;
    public TransformGroup _transformGroup;
    public CompositeTransform _compositeTransform;

    public ElementTransform()
    {
        _transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
        _previousTransform = new MatrixTransform() { Matrix = Matrix.Identity };
        _compositeTransform = new CompositeTransform();
        _transformGroup.Children.Add(_previousTransform);
        _transformGroup.Children.Add(_compositeTransform);   
    }

}
```

In the `UpdateQuote` method, you could use the global `Dictionary` to bind `TransformGroup` with `UIElement` like the follow:

```
if (element is TextBlock)
{
    TextBlock temp = element as TextBlock;
    var EleTrs = new ElementTransform();

    temp.RenderTransform = EleTrs._transformGroup;
    if (_ElementTrsDir.ContainsKey(temp)) return;
    _ElementTrsDir.Add(temp, EleTrs);

}
```

**Usage**

```
void OBJManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBlock)
    {
        TextBlock temp = sender as TextBlock;

        if (forceManipulationsToEnd)
        {
            e.Complete();
            return;
        }

        var EleTrs = _ElementTrsDir[temp];

        EleTrs._previousTransform.Matrix = EleTrs._transformGroup.Value;
        Windows.Foundation.Point center = EleTrs._previousTransform.TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point(e.Position.X, e.Position.Y));

        EleTrs._compositeTransform.CenterX = center.X;
        EleTrs._compositeTransform.CenterY = center.Y;

        EleTrs._compositeTransform.Rotation = (e.Delta.Rotation * 180) / Math.PI;
        EleTrs._compositeTransform.ScaleX = EleTrs._compositeTransform.ScaleY = e.Delta.Scale;
        EleTrs._compositeTransform.TranslateX = e.Delta.Translation.X;
        EleTrs._compositeTransform.TranslateY = e.Delta.Translation.Y;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Please note, for performance you could not set `UIElement` `RenderTransform` in the `OBJManipulationStarted` event handler.